# How to scope a callback function to be called from within a block?

Tags: javascript, typescript, scope

I'm using a third-party API which requires a callback function called `callback_data(json)` when the response comes back.

However, it seems to be calling `callback_data(json)` at the global scope. I would like to scope the `callback_data(json)` function within a block so that I can control the flow through promise.

Here's my attempt to do this:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
            (function(callback_data) {
                api.request({"q": term});   //The third-party API call
            })(function(json) {
                resolve({...json.data, q: term})
            });
        }
    );
```

So, the line `api.request({"q": term});` will call `callback_data(json)` function when it receives the response from the server. But it calls the callback function at the global scope. I want it to call from within the block the `api.request()` was initiated.

What I did was I thought I could put everything into a self invoking function and pass in the `callback_data(json)` function as a parameter into the self invoking function. I thought this would scope everything within that self invoking function block. Unfortunately, this didn't work.

How can I do scope a callback function, which supposed to be at the global scope, to be called from within a block?

I'm using Typescript in my code.

Comment: This sounds like JSONP. It works by returning a script that gets loaded in a new `<script>` tag. It can't access names that are local to another function, you have to assign your function to a global name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the API is really coded such that it issues:

```
callback_data(json);
```

...from within a scope you can't add functions to, there's nothing you can do. The API is badly designed (unless it's JSONP, in which case that's the only way it *can* work, but it should let you specify the name of the function) and `callback_data` must be global.

That doesn't mean that it has to be long-lived. You can declare it globally:

```
var callback_data = null; // At global scope
```

...and then in your code, assign a value to it and clear that value when done:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
    callback_data = function() { // Assign
        callback_data = null;    // Clear on callback
        resolve({...json.data,
            q: term
        });
    };
    api.request({"q": term});
});
```

If it's JSONP and it lets you specify the callback name in the request, that would be better as you can create a different callback name for each request:

```
// Using `window` as JSONP is by definition in a browser
window.lastCallbackId = 0;
return new Promise(resolve => {
    ++lastCallbackId;
    var name = "myCallback" + lastCallbackId;
    window[name] = function() { // Assign, will be "myCallback1", "myCallback2", ...
        window[name] = null;    // Clear on callback
        resolve({...json.data,
            q: term
        });
    };
    api.request({
        "q": term,
        callbackName: name  // Note passing the name to it
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I have a better idea for what's going on. Since I'm using Typescript and I had everything in a class, what I did was I tried to have a class variable as `private callback_data:(json)=>void;` and I followed the rest like what you did in your example, assigning the function to `this.callback_data`. However, it seems like class variables aren't at the global scope and it didn't work. What should I be doing if I had things in a class already?

Comment: @Carven: Having it in a class doesn't really change anything above. You need to make the callback global. `this` in a class instance method isn't global. As with the second example above, you probably need to put it on `window`. Also ensure that the counter you use (`lastCallbackId`) is a single counter used by all instances (unlike the actual callback variable, it doesn't have to be global, just common to the class).